# Boundedness criterion for a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $x_1=0$.
$x_{n+1}=ax_{n}+\frac{1}{n}$ where $a>0$.
Prove that $x_n$ is bounded iff $0<a<1$.

In the if part, 
we have $x_{n+1}-x_{n}<\frac{1}{n}$
From this we get $x_n<\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}$.
But I cannot show that the sequence is uniformly bounded.
No ideas for the only if part.

Comment: In the if part you have not used the fact that $0<\alpha<1$. Moreover, $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^{-1}$ is not bounded.

Comment: Hint: prove that your recurrence has the closed form
$$
x_n = \frac1{n-1} + \frac{a}{n-2}+\frac{a^2}{n-3}+\dots+\frac{a^{n-2}}{1}
$$

Comment: We have $x_2=1.$ If $a\geq 1$ then  use induction on $n \geq 2:$  If $x_n\geq  S(n-1)=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(1/j)$  then $x_{n+1}=$ $ax_n+1/n\geq x_n+1/n\geq $ 
 $S(n-1)+1/n=S(n).$

Comment: @MikeEarnest. Very good. Solves everything.